# Sql: joining two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables called `mp_Blogs` and `mp_BlogCategories`

`mp_blog` has columns and values

```
 ItemID   ModuleID 
   3         11
   4         11
   5         13
```

`mp_BlogCategories` has column and values

```
 CategoryID ModuleID 
   1         11
   2         11
   3         13
```

I need the output like this

```
 ItemID   CategoryID
   3         1
   4         2
   5         3
```

I used this query

```
SELECT a.[ItemID],b.[CategoryID] 
from [mp_Blogs] a 
    join [mp_BlogCategories] b 
        on a.ModuleID=b.ModuleID
```

But its coming in different way

```
 ItemID   CategoryID
   3         1
   4         1
   3         2
   4         2
   5         3
```

I used groupby function also but output same as before,any mistake in query 
how to get my original output

```
SELECT a.[ItemID],b.[CategoryID] 
from [mp_Blogs] a 
    join [mp_BlogCategories] b 
        on a.ModuleID=b.ModuleID  
group by b.CategoryID,a.ItemID
```

Comment: Which rule do you want to use to have ItemId=3->CatId=1 and ItemId=4->CatId=2? They both have ModuleId=11, so how can you _decide_?

Comment: actually itemid and catid is identity column so is there any other way to get that actual output

Comment: Yes, you have a problem with your content or your tables definition. Items 3 & 4 are both linked to categories 1 & 2 if the ModuleId is the only key. I suspect you're lacking another key.

Answer (score 0):

You query is performing properly but there is problem with data in you table as you can see the table contains 11 id two time thats y its giving the result like that. its better to check out the data in table.

Comment: i checked the table its like that only for both ItemId=3->CatId=1 and ItemId=4->CatId=2 have same moduleid=11 ,so this there any other way to get my original output

Answer (score 0):

From the Output it seems there is something wrong with the Data, not the Query.

Comment: i checked the table its like that only for both ItemId=3->CatId=1 and ItemId=4->CatId=2 have same moduleid=11 ,so this there any other way to get my original output

Comment: @Chandru: did you read my comment? The problem is: which is the reason you choose CatId=1 for ItemId=3 and CatId=2 for ItemId=4 when they share the same ModuleId? Why? Explain please, because we don't understand...

Comment: @Marco : In our website if the user is created new page and its affects the module table so moduleid also created  in that page they add new feature called blog its hit table called mp_blog u can see the table structure in my post and obviously we have category in our blog so its hit the table mp_blogcategory now what we going to do means i am going get the itemid and categoryid for that particular module and  insert into mp_blogitemcategory and there field  (itemid and categoryid)

Answer (score 0):

After reading comments you are lacking for unique key in both the tables
so i suggest you to add key in both the tables in order to achieve your result.

How it would be - tested in mysql working fine.

```
-- id column primary key in mp_blog table.

create table mp_blog(id smallint(5),ItemID smallint(5),
ModuleID smallint(5),constraint mp_blog_id primary key(id));

insert into mp_Blog values(1,3,11),(2,4,11),(3,5,13);

-- id column foreign key references to mp_blog primary key id.

create table mp_BlogCategories(id smallint(5),CategoryID smallint(5),
ModuleID smallint(5),constraint fk_mp_blogc foreign key(id) references mp_blog(id));

insert into mp_BlogCategories values(1,1,11),(2,2,11),(3,3,13);

-- finally what you are trying to achieve..

select b.itemid,bc.categoryid
from mp_blog b INNER JOIN mp_BlogCategories bc
on b.id=bc.id;


 ItemID   CategoryID
   3         1
   4         2
   5         3
```

Comment: ItemID and Categoryid is Identity column in my table i need to insert into the table called [mp_BlogItemCategories] the field is
ID(Identity),ItemID,CategoryID

itemid(column) is in different table  and categoryid(column) is in different table

if i gave my moduleid=11 

in my mp_BlogItemCategories table 
Id 1
ItemId:3,4
CategoryID:1,2

how i have to do this